# bash - proper use of grep's infix operator "|"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having a hard time discovering which method is best...
(debian latest, gnome)

This works;

```
$ ls -1 | grep "JPG|RAF|TIF"
```

I am trying to replace the "JPG|RAF|TIF" with a variable

e.g.

```
$ xFILTER="JPG RAF TIF"
```

I've tried to assign to the xFILTER variable...

> 1. xFILTER="JPG\|RAF\|TIF"
> 2. xFILTER="\"JPG|RAF|TIF\""
> 3. xFILTER="JPG\nRAF\nTIF"

- $ ls -1 | grep -E "$xFILTER"
- $ ls -1 | grep -e $xFILTER
- $ ls -1 | grep -E "$(echo "xFILTER" | tr ' ' '|')"

Could someone please direct me towards a more sensible approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: If your goal is to list files for use in a script, no approach using `ls -1 | grep` is sensible. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: `filters='*.jpg *.raf *.tif'; for file in $filters; do echo "Found file: $file"; done`... if you really _must_ get the filters from a scalar variable. Doing so is not a particularly good practice in general, though. `files=( *.jpg *.raf *.tif ); for file in "${files[@]}"` is better, if you can store the filenames rather than the filters in a variable. You might want to use `shopt -s nocaseglob`, by the way.

Comment: On a different note -- `grep` is not part of `bash`; it's a standard UNIX tool (bundled by your OS distributor), and works the same way whether you're using any shell or no shell at all. Inasmuch as this question is about grep's behavior, then, it's not really a bash question as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
xFILTER="JPG|RAF|TIF"

ls -1 | grep -E "$xFILTER"
```

However as a word of caution it is not always good to parse `ls` output when your files can have spaces or new lines. Look into `shopt -s extglob` to enable extended globbing and search your files by extended patterns.

Comment: Not just spaces and newlines -- a great many other assorted nonprintable characters can be represented in interesting nonliteral ways by `ls` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into the different regular expressions syntaxes that grep supports.

Quoting the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep),

> In  basic  regular  expressions the metacharacters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions  \?, +, {, \|, (, and ).

I'm surprised that you say your first example works.
Use one of the following:

```
xFILTER="JPG\|RAF\|TIF" ; ls -1 | grep $xFILTER
xFILTER="JPG|RAF|TIF" ; ls -1 | grep -E $xFILTER
```

Comment: The backslash versions are a GNU extension not present in POSIX BRE. Better not to rely on them.